# iOS 7 UIDatePicker in UIAlertView customisation

Tags: ios, uialertview, uidatepicker, ios7

Guys I was adding UIDatePicker to UIAlertView like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273572/uidatepicker-customization)

[image]

It was fine with iOS 6 and below now in iOS 7 it comes like this

[image]

Any ideas why this happens? Is there a better way of doing this?.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my component to support addSubview in AlertView.

[CXAlertView](https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXAlertView) - Custom alert-view which allow you to add view as main content.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can change *accessoryView* to any own *customContentView* in a standard alert view in iOS7

```
[alertView setValue:customContentView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Note that you must call this before *[alertView show]*.

Simplest illustrating example:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[av setValue:v forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[av show];
```

[image]

Exactly in the same way you can add your *DatePicker*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no fix for this. Adding subviews to a UIAlertView was never supported and in iOS 7 this lead to subviews not showing. Some workarounds have been posted on the Apple Developer Forums, but they could easily break in a future release.

I suggest file a bug report. Many others (including myself) have done this, and the more requests Apple gets for it, the higher its priority becomes.

**EDIT:** I have written a `UIAlertView` clone that does allow for adding subviews: [`SDCAlertView`](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView).

Comment: Thanks, I knew this is not the best way but my app needed this.

Comment: Yes, many people need it. That's why filing a bug is so important.

Comment: Would file a bug for sure.

Answer (score 3):

On iOS7, you should use the new custom modal transition support in UIKit using `UIModalPresentationCustom` and `transitioningDelegate`.

Using these, you can create a view similar to that of an alert view, but custom, where you could add a date picker.

More information here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported and I dont belive they 'fix this' .. roll your own alert view or use a open source alternative. see also [UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using a UIView instead of UIAlertView or some open source component.